# Is the webpack style loader meant to load all css? Or just application specific css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, amd, webpack

I'm trying to make my front-end design process more modular, and am exploring [webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack). It supports a [style loader](https://github.com/webpack/style-loader), which allows you import a css file and inject it in the document like so:

```
require("style/url!file!./file.css");
// => add a <link rel="stylesheet"> to file.css to document
```

However, my main focus is on websites and not webapps<sup>1</sup>, so it feels weird to add the css through javascript. But I might just be old fashioned, so I'm wondering: is the  loader meant to be used for all css, or is it only meant to load small, conditional parts of css?

And if it can be used for loading all css, would there be any penalties when using a webpack generated `bundle.js` to inject the css as opposed to directly linking a css file in the html? Besides it obviously breaking if javascript isn't enabled?

---

*1: The difference being that I have very little dynamic content, javascript plays only a minor role in these websites, and that I'm not routing with javascript but have static .html files for pages*

Comment: There is a way to separate the css into a separate file btw: https://webpack.github.io/docs/stylesheets.html#separate-css-bundle

Comment: CSS loaded through javascript would take longer to load as well

Answer (score 15):

Where possible, include CSS with the HTML itself.  Modern browsers will begin fetching the CSS as the page is parsing, sometimes before the JavaScript has even begun to download.  You're going to get an improvement in page rendering speed doing major pieces outside of a loader.

Additionally, if you stick to a major "core" style, you can benefit from caching, which will again load faster than JavaScript can.

http://csswizardry.com/2013/01/front-end-performance-for-web-designers-and-front-end-developers/

---

In your example, I've done it by splitting it into multiple pieces and using loaders & bundlers for the specific elements I've got loaded in the page.  The application look & feel, branding, etc is loaded from markup, and the behavior that controls my specific UI (say, layout for a particular form) is done with a bundler or packer.

Comment: Chrome and Firefox 50+ both download CSS and JS at the same time.